# Extract large data in Postgresql using python(preferbly in dataframe format)

Tags: psycopg2

I have imported many large csv files into tables to my postgresql database, I know how to connect to the database with this code:

```
import psycopg2
try:
   connection = psycopg2.connect(user = "xxx",
                              password = "xxx",
                              host = "xxx",
                              port = "xxx",
                              database = "xxx")

   cursor = connection.cursor()
   # Print PostgreSQL Connection properties
   print ( connection.get_dsn_parameters(),"\n")

   # Print PostgreSQL version
   cursor.execute("SELECT version();")
   record = cursor.fetchone()
   print("You are connected to - ", record,"\n")

except (Exception, psycopg2.Error) as error :
   print ("Error while connecting to PostgreSQL", error)
finally:
   #closing database connection.
    if(connection):
        cursor.close()
        connection.close()
        print("PostgreSQL connection is closed")
```

But I struggle to extract data from here, is it possible to transform these tables to dataframe format, since I will be doing some ML analysis on these tables.

I'm new to Postgresql, please help me with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do it.
A very simple way would be to iterate through the cursor with fetchall()

```
cursor.execute(query)
rows = cursor.fetchall()
data = []
for row in rows:
   data.append({'field1':row[0],'field2':row[1])})
```

If you are using Pandas Dataframe, you could do:

```
rows = pd.DataFrame(rows,columns=['field1','field2'])
```

Comment: Since my data is really big I set a name to cursor as cur = con.cursor('mycursor'), to make it server sided. But I got an error:    <ipython-input-33-77a97c7c7f20> in <module>
      3     cur = con.cursor('mycursor')
      4 #     cur.execute("set search_path to mimiciii")
----> 5     cur.execute("SELECT * FROM admissions")
      6 
      7     ad = cur.fetchall()

ProgrammingError: relation "admissions" does not exist
LINE 1: ... "mycursor" CURSOR WITHOUT HOLD FOR SELECT * FROM admissions